# Checkbox looks differentin firefox and ie when styling with css

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, input

i want to style my checkbox,

but when i applies the properties. it looks weird in firefox & IE,

Please help me out here is the fiddle

JSFIDDLE

Comment: Link to the fiddle is missing?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bS432/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete properties about  -moz-appearance:none;
                         -webkit-appearance:none;
and it will work

http://jsbin.com/yubukuna/2/edit